# Where is the email New release(s) available coming from

Tags: notifications

With Drupal 7, we are getting some emails that say **"New release(s) available for name of site"** , but they are going to someone who doesn't work here any more, and they are bouncing back to me.

Where are these emails coming from, they seem to be from drupal but I can't find where this is configured.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's configured on the "Available updates" settings page at /admin/reports/updates/settings:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Remove email address present at **admin/reports/updates/settings**.